# Swap images from PHP array with Ajax and also get ID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, swap

On my website an user is able to fill in an url. When he fills in the url, he gets all the images src's from that url. I push these src's to an array in php:

```
 array_push($goodfiles,$pic);
```

Now the user will be able to choose on of the pictures (with a next or prev button) and then save it to the database. The picture that's saved is based on the id of the image in the array. So $goodfiles['0'] means id = "0" and so on.

I want the swapping of the images to work with ajax, so that the pages doesn't have to refresh all the time when clicking the next or previous button. And then when I save the form, I want to know the id of the current image, so that I can save it to the database.

How do I realize this with Ajax (jquery)?

Edit:

This is how I do it right now:

```
    $current_id = $_GET['id'];
if(empty($_GET['id']) || !empty($empty)) { $current_id = 0; }
$prev_id = $_GET['id'] - 1;
if($prev_id < 0){ $prev_id = 0;}
$next_id = $_GET['id'] + 1;
if($next_id > $_SESSION['count']-1 && $_SESSION['count'] != 'empty') { $next_id = $_SESSION['count']-1;}
```

This is the code for the pagination

And this is the pagination:

```
        <div id="url_pic">

        <img src="<?=$_SESSION['pictures'][$current_id]?>" class="img_load"><br>
        <? if($_SESSION['count'] > 1) { ?><center><a href="additem_url.php?id=<?=$prev_id?>"><img src="img/add/left.png"></a> <a href="additem_url.php?id=<?=$next_id?>"><img src="img/add/right.png"></a></center> <? } ?>

    </div>
```

So right now my solution doesn't contain any javascript, but it's all php coded. And the page refreshes everytime you want to see the next picture. I want to solve this in ajax, so that you can paginate through the images without a refresh. The way I want it is like this link:

```
 http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm
```

But except for the text, I want to paginate through images.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to use AJAX for this. Simply return a html file containing a JavaScript array, which contains all those image URLs and do the other stuff using JavaScript.

Get back to StackOverflow in case you've a more precise question and hopefully some code, which we can help on ;)

Answer (score 0):

Load a script at the bottom of your php page the user side of the PHP where all your HTML is, above the closing body tag thats something loosely similar to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myPHParray); ?>
</script>
```

this way when your page loads out it renders with a dynamic javascript json object as a variable that you can work with client side, this removes the need for an AJAX request all together unless your doing stuff with the data your playing with. From first glance Im guessing not really per say. But yea, at the very least its one less transaction to be made when the page is loading.

edit just noticed someone said similar while I was typing out.. Lars.. so I guess this is a follow up to his answer :-D